# When I try to run speech recognition in pyqt5 program is crashed

Tags: python, pyqt, speech-recognition

When I try to run speech recognition in pyqt5 program is crashed. Sr's code is at the another script file. I import it to pyqt5 script. I connected button with sr function. When I press the button sr work but crashs both.

PyQt5 Code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,QtGui
from Speech_Recognition import Voice



def Gui():

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    window.setGeometry(200,200,150,150)


    button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(window)
    button1.setText("Start")
    button1.clicked.connect(Voice)


    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


Gui()
```

Speech Recognition

```
import speech_recognition as sr

text = ""


def Voice():

    r = sr.Recognizer()
    m = sr.Microphone()



    while True:
        print("Say somethig!")
        with m as source:
            audio = r.listen(source)
            print("Got it! Now to recognize it...")

            try:

                value = r.recognize_google(audio)
                text = value
                print("You said: {}".format(text))

            except sr.UnknownValueError:
                print("Oops")
```

Comment: Why do you connect the clicked signal with Voice?, provide a [mcve]

Comment: Because I want to when press the button another script file (speech recognition) run. How ı do this. The Voice is function of sr script file.

Comment: @Laccazet If you do not provide an MCVE it is impossible to help you, most likely the cause of the error is in the code that you do not show.

Comment: @eyllanesc
That's all the codes

Comment: @Laccazet You should not modify your code but my answer will not make sense for future users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a while True that will block the eventloop of the GUI, in those cases it is advisable to execute that task in another thread:

```py
import sys
import threading
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

from Speech_Recognition import Voice


def on_clicked():
    th = threading.Thread(target=Voice)
    th.daemon = True
    th.start()


def Gui():

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    window.setGeometry(200, 200, 150, 150)

    button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(window)
    button1.setText("Start")
    button1.clicked.connect(on_clicked)

    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


Gui()
```

**Plus:**

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import speech_recognition as sr

class VoiceWorker(QtCore.QObject):
    textChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def task(self):
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        m = sr.Microphone()

        while True:
            print("Say somethig!")
            with m as source:
                audio = r.listen(source)
                print("Got it! Now to recognize it...")
                try:
                    value = r.recognize_google(audio)
                    self.textChanged.emit(value)
                    print("You said: {}".format(text))
                except sr.UnknownValueError:
                    print("Oops")

def Gui():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    worker = VoiceWorker()
    thread = QtCore.QThread()
    thread.start()
    worker.moveToThread(thread)

    window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    window.setGeometry(200, 200, 350, 400)
    window.setWindowTitle("Assistant") 

    title_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(window)
    title_label.setText("Assistant")
    title_label.move(135,10)
    title_label.setFont(QtGui.QFont("SansSerif", 15))

    programs_says = QtWidgets.QLabel(window)
    programs_says.setText("Programs Says")
    programs_says.move(240,100)

    you_says = QtWidgets.QLabel(window)
    you_says.move(25,100)


    you_text = QtWidgets.QLabel(window)
    worker.textChanged.connect(you_text.setText)
    you_text.move(25,150) 


    start_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start")
    close_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Close")


    v_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    v_box.addStretch()
    v_box.addWidget(start_button)
    v_box.addWidget(close_button)
    window.setLayout(v_box)

    start_button.clicked.connect(worker.task)
    close_button.clicked.connect(QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


Gui()
```

Comment: Speech Recognition is converting my voice to text. I want to equal Sr text and pyqt label. I changed the code. The text variable is coming from speech recognition script.

Comment: @Laccazet It seems that you do not know anything about Qt, just for this opportunity I will show you how to do it. If you have another doubt then create another question